# Specify custom location for Rubygems to install via package type

Tags: ruby, vagrant, puppet, vagrant-provision

I've installed Ruby in a custom location (on an Ubuntu box, into /opt/rubies using ruby-install) and when it comes to declarations like this:

```
  package { 'bundler':
    ensure   => 'installed',
    provider => 'gem',
    require =>  Exec["Install Ruby"],
  }
```

They fail (or install for the wrong version of Ruby) because it's looking for the Rubygems' `gem` command in the wrong place (/usr/bin). I can think of a few ways I might fix this:

1. Tell `package` which version of `gem` I want used, but I don't see anything in [the docs for that](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/4.3/reference/type.html#package).
2. Add the correct bin directory to the PATH, but I don't know which user is running the provisioner and hence, where to change the PATH. Or should I change the path along with the Ruby installation?
3. Using an `exec` declaration instead.

Obviously, using `package` is very convenient so any way to keep using that would be my preference. Any help or insight will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep using `package`, you have two options:

- You can change the `PATH` that the puppet agent runs on.
- You can subclass the provider with the desired `gem` path. Like [this](https://github.com/sensu/sensu-puppet/blob/master/lib/puppet/provider/package/sensu_gem.rb), except you don't need to replace the `uninstall` method, so you can lose that part. Then you'll change `provider => gem` to `provider => whatever_provider_name_you_chose`.

Comment: Thank you, that link looks very interesting.